# Is there a proof of the Krull Intersection Theorem without using the Artin-Rees lemma?

Tags: commutative-algebra

Textbooks on commutative algebra always prove the Krull Intersection Theorem using the Artin-Rees lemma. But is it really necessary to do so? Can one prove the Krull Intersection Theorem without using the Artin-Rees lemma? Is it even possible? I would like to see such a proof.

Comment: Check out the paper ``Two classical theorems of ideal theory'' by Rees. You can find a beautiful proof there. It is also interesting to note that Rees proves the Artin-Rees lemma in the same paper, but he uses the lemma to prove Krull's height theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduce the proof from the [CRing project](http://math.uchicago.edu/%7Eamathew/CRing.pdf), which in turn cites ''Hervé Perdry. An elementary proof of Krull’s intersection theorem. *The American Mathematical Monthly*, 111(4):356–357, 2004''.

---

**Theorem.** Suppose $R$ is a noetherian ring, $I \subset R$ an ideal. Suppose $b \in \bigcap I^n$. Then, $(b) = (b) I$, as ideals.

Note that the theorem implies the intersection $\bigcap I^n$ to be zero under either of the following condition:

1. $I$ is contained in the Jacobson radical of $R$. (In particular, $R$ is local, and $I$ is the maximal ideal.)
2. $R$ is a domain and $I \neq R$.

*Proof of the Theorem.* Let $a_1, \ldots, a_k \in I$ be generators of $I$. Note that $I^n$ is generated by all monomials of degree $n$ in the $a_i$. Thus, if $b \in \bigcap I^n$, then for each $n$, there exists a homogeneous polynomial $P_n \in R[x_1, \ldots, x_k]$ of degree $n$ such that
$$b = P_n(a_1, \ldots, a_k).$$
Now, note that the ideal $(P_1, P_2, \ldots)$ is itself finitely generated since $R[x_1, \ldots, x_k]$ is noetherian.
Thus, there exist $N > 0$ and polynomials $Q_i$ such that
$$P_{N + 1} = Q_1 P_1 + \cdots + Q_N P_N.$$
Note that since the $P_i$ are all homogeneous of degree $i$, we may pick $Q_i$ to be homogeneous of degree $N + 1 - i > 0$. (We only need that the $Q_i$s have no constant term.)
Now, evaluating the above expression at $a_1, \ldots, a_k$ gives
$$b = b\underbrace{(Q_1(a_1, \ldots, a_k) + \cdots + Q_N(a_1, \ldots, a_k))}_{\in I}.$$
Thus, $b \in (b)I$. $\hspace{1cm} \Box$